# Reach server linux inside network

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have installed a new Ubuntu server inside my network with ip 192.168.1.253.

I can reach by ssh to it but if I search it from a mac or pc I can't find the server.

With mac I have tried:

```
network-> smb://192.168.1.253
```

The connection go in timeout.

What should I do to reach my new server from my network?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and configure `Samba`; Samba is not included in the default installation.

Note that you should be able to `ping` that machine, and as well `ssh` into it (if not, you must install `openssh` as well).

Comment: to reach a server I really need Samba? Because I have another server where installed is already installed (IP: 192.168.1.254)

Comment: Yes, if you want to connect with SMB/CIFS, you need to install Samba. If you can live with using an SCP client (like Transmit or Cyberduck) instead of the Finder, you don't need Samba.

Comment: @WebDesigner: You try to access the server with the SMB protocol (or CIFS, which is oftenly referred to as SMB). Something on that target machine must speak that protocol, so that it can answer. And that *something* is Samba.

Comment: @SvW: You still need an `sshd` running though, if you want to use *scp*/*sftp*. I don't know if openssh-server is part of the default Ubuntu install.

Comment: @datenwolf: He said he can reach the system by SSH, so OpenSSH is installed.

Comment: ok I don't want to install samba I would like to have a quick mode to access by other computer to my linux server without usigng ssh because many person aren't developer and don't know how to you shell @SvW

Comment: @WebDesigner: If you have SSH installed you can use SFTP to access the server (this works like FTP but is more secure). There are many very good GUI clients available that allow you to access the files on the server in a very similar way to the SMB/Finder combination (e.g. Cyberduck, Filezilla or Transmit).

Comment: ok perfect, I have tried but don't find the host, I think that I have to install something @SvW

Comment: @WebDesigner: If something like "host not found" is reported, then you're dealing most like with a network configuration probkem. *"No route to host"* means, that the other box is not reacting to any connection attempt at all. If you simply can't connect with a specific service on the box, the error message was "Connection refused".